# google+ - change layout and delete multiple photos

Tags: google-plus

Do you know how to select multiple photos in Google+ Photos? (not only one by one, but multiselection with Shift)

I found these help - https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1407859?hl=en-GB but in my account there is no option Move to bin.

How can I change layout of the Photos as you can see in the Joe's account (from tutorial on Youtube - Deleting individual photos from Google+ Albums)?

Illustration: http://s22.postimg.org/leq53frs1/ilustration.jpg

Images description: Joe's account - Organize albums | Joe's account - there IS a button to move to bin or another album | My account - Organize albums | My account - there is no button to move to bin or another album.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

22.09.2013: in Firefox and in Opera now works fine.